# Optimize value with linear (or non-linear?) constraints in R

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, linear-programming

I am trying to pick the best possible fantasy football team given different constraints. My goal is to *pick the players that maximize the sum of their projected points*.

The constraints are:

1) The team must include:

-1 QB

-2 RBs

-2 WRs

-1 TE

2) A player's risk must not exceed 6

3) The sum of the players' costs must not exceed 300.

How can I do this?  What is the best package/function in R to optimize these constraints?  What would the function call look like to maximize the projected points given these constraints?  FYI, I'll be searching through 100-300 players.

Thanks in advance!  Here is a small example data set:

```
name <- c("Aaron Rodgers","Tom Brady","Arian Foster","Ray Rice","LeSean McCoy","Calvin Johnson","Larry Fitzgerald","Wes Welker","Rob Gronkowski","Jimmy Graham")

pos <- c("QB","QB","RB","RB","RB","WR","WR","WR","TE","TE")

pts <- c(167, 136, 195, 174, 144, 135, 89, 81, 114, 111) 

risk <- c(2.9, 3.4, 0.7, 1.1, 3.5, 5.0, 6.7, 4.7, 3.7, 8.8) 

cost <- c(60, 47, 63, 62, 40, 60, 50, 35, 40, 40) 

mydata <- data.frame(name, pos, pts, risk, cost)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. :-) What have you tried already? It's an interesting problem but people here will want to see that you have had a first stab at putting something together. Also 4 spaces at the start of lines with code formats it as a code block.

Comment: Are you planning on searching through all players? How many players would you like to search through? For your example there are only 2*3*3*2=36 teams. but if there are 100 players there would be about 20*20*(30*29/2)*(30*29)/2=7590000 possible teams.

Comment: Hi Simon and Seth, Thanks.  I am able to do this optimization in using Excel's solver function, but I'm not familiar with how to do linear optimization in R.  I see there are lots of different functions, but I'm not sure which would be the most relevant for my type of problem, and I have no experience writing the arguments for an optimization function in R.  Any help would be much appreciated.  By the way, I'm searching through about 100-300 players.

Comment: This seems like a nice example:   http://fishyoperations.com/r/linear-programming-in-r-an-lpsolveapi-example/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=linear-programming-in-r-an-lpsolveapi-example

Comment: @dadrivr Don't forget to accept Flodel's response, if it adequately addressed your question. You can do that by checking the tick mark next to the response. It is small way of 'rewarding' the respondent for the time they took to help you out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your constraints and objective are linear, but your variables are binaries: whether each player should be picked or not. So your problem is a little more general than a Linear Programming (LP), it is a Mixed-Integer Programming (MIP). On CRAN's [Optimization Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html), look for their MIP section.

CPLEX is a commercial solver you probably not have access to, but GLPK is free. If I were you, I would probably go with the high level interface [Rglpk](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rglpk/index.html).

It will require you put your problem in matrix form, I suggest you look at the documentation and examples.

---

**Edit:** Here is an implementation:

```
# We are going to solve:
# maximize f'x subject to A*x <dir> b
# where:
#   x is the variable to solve for: a vector of 0 or 1:
#     1 when the player is selected, 0 otherwise,
#   f is your objective vector,
#   A is a matrix, b a vector, and <dir> a vector of "<=", "==", or ">=",
#   defining your linear constraints.

# number of variables
num.players <- length(name)
# objective:
f <- pts
# the variable are booleans
var.types <- rep("B", num.players)
# the constraints
A <- rbind(as.numeric(pos == "QB"), # num QB
           as.numeric(pos == "RB"), # num RB
           as.numeric(pos == "WR"), # num WR
           as.numeric(pos == "TE"), # num TE
           diag(risk),              # player's risk
           cost)                    # total cost

dir <- c("==",
         "==",
         "==",
         "==",
         rep("<=", num.players),
         "<=")

b <- c(1,
       2,
       2,
       1,
       rep(6, num.players),
       300)

library(Rglpk)
sol <- Rglpk_solve_LP(obj = f, mat = A, dir = dir, rhs = b,
                      types = var.types, max = TRUE)
sol
# $optimum
# [1] 836                      ### <- the optimal total points

# $solution
#  [1] 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0     ### <- a `1` for the selected players

# $status
# [1] 0                        ### <- an optimal solution has been found

# your dream team
name[sol$solution == 1]
# [1] "Aaron Rodgers"  "Arian Foster"   "LeSean McCoy"
# [4] "Calvin Johnson" "Wes Welker"     "Rob Gronkowski
```

Comment: This is really great and very helpful.  The only thing that appears to be missing is the constraint that the sum of the players' cost should be less than 300.  Right now, the cost of the solution is 320.  It appears that the 'dir' and 'b' matrices are set up correctly for the constraint, but the last line of the 'A' matrix is not.  I tried changing it to: diag(cost), but that did not work.  We want it to reflect the sum of only the selected players.  How can I modify the last line of the A matrix to achieve that?  Thanks so much---this looks wonderful!

Comment: @dadrivr: sorry, it is now fixed, the last row of `A` needed to be `cost`. The final cost is `sum(cost * sol$solution)`: 298.